# QGIS 3.x adding a layer too the root of the project instead of the selected group

Tags: qgis-3, layers, pyqgis-3

I''ve created a function to add layers to a QGIS project:

```
def add_layer_to_project(layer, group_lst=None, visible=True):
    """
    group name has to be list relative to root of project
    root
        group
            subgroup
                subsubgroup for example
    """
    try:
        root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        # If group is specified, create it if it doesn't exist yet
        if group_lst:
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
            # Last item in list represent group to add layer to
            group = ensure_group(group_lst, root)
            group.addLayer(layer)
        else:
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, visible)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e from None
```

I call the function like this:

```
add_layer_to_project(layer)
```

Layer can be raster or vector layer and is created elsewhere.

The intent is to add a layer to either a group in my project or to the root of it. However, if I have a group selected and I try to add layers to the root (see `else` clause), they get added to that group instead. I haven't tried what happens if I try to create a group but I imagine it somehow sees whatever is selected as the root? I was hoping someone could tell my how to make sure that `root` is actually the root if the layer tree.

(P.S. I have found a lot of answers that describe how to add layers to a group, but I couldn't find this)

P.S. The `ensure_group` function just creates groups and subgroups if needed, I didn't think I should paste the code since the problem occurs when it isn't called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the same logic in your `else` clause as you do in your first condition.

E.g. In your else clause you should add the layer to the project without adding it to the legend:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
```

Then add it to the layer tree root:

```
root.addLayer(layer)
```

Note that `addLayer()` appends the layer node to the end of a group. To have greater control over the position of added layers you can use the `insertLayer()` method, passing the index of the position at which the layer node should be added as the first argument. For example, to insert a layer at the top of the Table Of Contents use:

```
root.insertLayer(0, layer)
```

Or at the top of a group:

```
group.insertLayer(0, layer)
```

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation too!